# Best way to port Javafx app as a Web App

Tags: java, web, javafx, web-applications

I have an application with a JavaFX interface, now I have to make it a web application as quickly as possibile.

What is the best way to approach this job? Which framework is the least time-consuming to learn and is possibly free?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write html and a lot of dirty web related stuff, I would suggest to use Vaadin (https://vaadin.com/framework).

Comment: Vaadin seems great but it would force me to write the UI by hand since the community version does not include the WYSIWYG editor... and I don't have 1000+$ to drop in a license.